# Rails loop and .join method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops, join

I have project and city table, and many-to-many relation between.

I want in html to get list of cities names, divided with ", ".

I tried with this:

```
<%= @project.cities(&:name).join(", ") %>
```

But I get (I think) object like this:

```
#<City:0x103886748>
```

Where I made a mistake? :|

P.S. Explanation:

I have @project that have one or more cities. I want to loop through cities and print names like this:
New York, Boston, Belgrade  (without comma on the end).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've forgot `map` here

```
<%= @project.cities.map(&:name).join(", ") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also a very cool built in helper to do that.

`to_sentence`

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-to_sentence

```
<%= @project.cities(&:name).map.to_sentence %>
```